# Hibernation causes mandatory fsck

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, filesystem, hibernate

Since I have a specific use-case I've enabled Hibernation on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation. The installation has it's own disk drive, with no other volumes mounted.

After booting back from hibernation I get prompted that there are unexpected inconsistencies. A manual mandatory fsck is required to continue booting. It fixes some inodes and then continues as expected.

There is a second drive in the system containing a Windows installation. While Ubuntu is hibernated I sometimes boot into that environment. I know that mounting hibernated volumes can cause filesystem issues, but Windows does not touch nor can read the Ubuntu volumes on the other disk. Both disks are also new, without any bad sectors or other issues.

Why is this happening? How serious is it? What can I do to prevent it?

Any information or insight would be greatly appreciated.